# Бесконечный слайдер на чистом JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

Делаю слайдер на чистом JS с помощью setInterval. Как можно добиться бесконечной прокрутки слайдов?

```js
let sliderWrapper = document.querySelector(".slider-wrapper");
let sliderElements = document.querySelectorAll(".slider-item");

const sliderItemWidth = sliderElements[0].clientWidth;
let counter = 1;

let translation = 0;

const nextSlide = function() {
  let start = Date.now(); // запомнить время начала

  let timer = setInterval(function() {
    let timePassed = Date.now() - start;

    nextBtn.classList.add("inactive-button");

    if (timePassed > sliderItemWidth) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        nextBtn.classList.remove("inactive-button");
      }, 400);
      clearInterval(timer);
      translation = sliderItemWidth * counter;
      counter++;
      return;
    }
    draw(timePassed);
  }, 0);

  function draw(timePassed) {
    sliderElements.forEach((item) => {
      item.style.right = translation + timePassed + "px";
    });
  }
};

const prevSlide = function() {
  let start = Date.now();
  let timer = setInterval(function() {
    let timePassed = Date.now() - start;

    prevBtn.classList.add("inactive-button");

    if (timePassed > sliderItemWidth + 1) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        prevBtn.classList.remove("inactive-button");
      }, 400);
      clearInterval(timer);
      translation = sliderItemWidth * (counter - 2);
      counter--;
      return;
    }
    draw(timePassed);
  }, 0);

  function draw(timePassed) {
    sliderElements.forEach((item) => {
      item.style.right = translation - timePassed + "px";
    });
  }
};

nextBtn.addEventListener("click", nextSlide);
prevBtn.addEventListener("click", prevSlide);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
  color: #fff;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.slider {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 800px;
}

.slider-wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.slider-item {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.slider-item-content {
  height: 250px;
  background: coral;
}

.slider-control {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0.5;
  height: 50px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.slider-control:hover,
.slider-control:focus {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: 0;
  opacity: .9;
}

.slider-control-left {
  left: 0;
}

.slider-control-right {
  right: 0;
}

.slider-control::before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: transparent no-repeat center center;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.slider-control-left::before {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23fff' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath d='M5.25 0l-4 4 4 4 1.5-1.5-2.5-2.5 2.5-2.5-1.5-1.5z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

.slider-control-right::before {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23fff' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath d='M2.75 0l-1.5 1.5 2.5 2.5-2.5 2.5 1.5 1.5 4-4-4-4z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

.slider-item>div {
  line-height: 250px;
  font-size: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.inactive-button {
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
  opacity: 0.1;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="slider-wrapper">
      <div class="slider-item">
        <div class="slider-item-content" style="background-color: aqua;">
          1
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slider-item">
        <div class="slider-item-content" style="background-color: orange;">
          2
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slider-item">
        <div class="slider-item-content" style="background-color: greenyellow;">
          3
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slider-item">
        <div class="slider-item-content" style="background-color: violet;">
          4
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a id="prevBtn" class="slider-control slider-control-left" href="#" role="button"></a>
    <a id="nextBtn" class="slider-control slider-control-right slider-control-show" href="#" role="button"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Запутанная логика у вас, конечно. Но в целом во формула, которой я успешно пользуюсь `currentSlideIndex = (currentSlideIndex + direction + image.length) % image.length`, где `direction` - это либо `+1` либо `-1`  в зависимости от направления

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Логика такова:

- Если кликаем на промотку вперёд и `counter` становится больше, чем общее количество фото, то скидываем его на 1. И дальше отображаем последнее фото на основе получившегося значения счётчика
- Если кликаем на промотку назад и `counter` становится меньше 1, то устанавливаем счётчик на "количество фото". И дальше отображаем последнее фото на основе получившегося значения счётчика